# Android App - Banner not displaying when APK is built or when app is debugged

Tags: android

The banner is not being displayed while the app is debugged on Android Studio. The banner displays perfectly fine on the program but when I debug the app, the banner isn't there.

What is causing the banner to disappear?

On Android Studio, the banner looks like this: [View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oIvs.png)

When the app is debugged, it looks like this: [View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZiXb.png)
(Notice that the blue banner is not there.)

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.second.app.foothillers">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".news">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="app.foothillers.news" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".photos">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="app.foothillers.photos" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".more">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="app.foothillers.more" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Sports">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="app.foothillers.Sports" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Style.xml**

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
      <!--  <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground"> @mipmap/ic_launcher </item> -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Can you copy the content of your style.xml file?

Comment: @Distwo I updated it.

Comment: Banner? You mean Toolbar or ActionBar?

Comment: Or that? If you take a look at the images, you'll have a clear image of what I am talking about.